# Is there a way to block an employer request after the fact?

Tags: support, feature-request, bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

I can respect that this is a rare edge case, but right now I've found myself in a scenario that has me wanting to reject future communications with a potential employer going forward.  This is after I've accepted the initial communication.

Is there a way for me to do that?  If there isn't, could it be baked into the platform at some point in the future?

Comment: Apart from just not communicating, I guess.

Comment: I've set this as a bug. We thought it worked this way as well. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -8):

There is!

From the [Jobs home page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) click the envelope icon in the top right to go to your inbox, or click [this direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/inbox). Then find the conversation with that employer and click on it. When you have the conversation open, there should be a big red button that says "Block Employer" near the top right.

[image]

Comment: That only seems to apply if you haven't already started a previous application with them.  I can see that on other messages which I've previously declined.

Comment: Ah, you're right. That only applies if they message you.