# Show / Hide company jobs in the search

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I'd like have the option to show/hide jobs from a specific company in the list; it could be an option right next to the company name in the list.

Also, I would like to have a page to manage the list of companies that are hidden from my custom job list, this filter will affect the job list on the right hand side when you are browsing questions, because is annoying to look at jobs from companies that you are not interested.

This could be an alternative to using `-company:name` in the text search every time you want to do a search.

Comment: (Potentially) related:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313016/1079354

Comment: First why the downvote?, second isn't the same basically what I'm asking is to have a way to exclude companies in the job search without using the "minus" sing in the search, then a way to administrate that list of companies and turn on/off from appearing in the job listing

Comment: Go easy there Jack; I didn't downvote anything.  I've only glanced at this and I believed it to be related to something that I had posted a while ago.  If it's not the same, could you clarify a bit more into what you're specifically looking for?  User stories have their place, but if you clarified your specific case then more people could understand and/or agree with what it is you're suggesting.

Comment: got it, I've updated my question.

Comment: @jack.the.ripper Re: managing your list of hidden companies - if you're still interested in this feature, please create a separate feature request. This will help us to track the request better.

Comment: @Donna I think you have done it with your latest update, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now show/hide jobs at a specific company using search filters. Thanks for the note.

[image]