# Hide a specific job listing from my search results

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

One feature I like from Zillow and Craigslist is the ability to *hide* a listing - I've reviewed the listing, found I'm not interested for whatever reason, so I don't want to see it again.

There is a star to add a listing to my favorites - how about an X to persistently get rid of one, sort of like "un-favorite" (wouldn't want to say "dislike" would we)?

**EDIT:  This is not the same as [Show / Hide company jobs in the search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325608/show-hide-company-jobs-in-the-search).**

The link above excludes every listing for a company.

I am talking about hiding *individual* job postings one at a time, after you've done a search, clicked on a posting, read it and decided "nope, this **one** is not for me - I'm not qualified, the company seems too weird, whatever" - so I'll click the "don't show me **this one** any more" button...  not excluding all jobs for a given company.

This request *is* very similar to [Allow users to hide individual job listings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312509/215552) which allows you to do the exact thing I want to do, *but only in ads.*

Comment: This looks a lot like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312509/215552...