# Custom Categories for Job Posts with Filtering Capability

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

This question/feature request is very similar to [Allow users to hide individual job listings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312509/allow-users-to-hide-individual-job-listings) and [Hide a specific job listing from my search results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340898/hide-a-specific-job-listing-from-my-search-results)
; however, I am taking it a little further and adding a twist.

SO already has the ability to "favorite" job posts.  It also appears to have the capability to remove job posts *from advertisements* (I haven't found a way to do so on the actual Jobs page).

I propose we merge these two ideas and expand on them.  Favorited and hidden posts are both sublists of the larger Jobs lists.  What I would like to see is a way to categorize posts into many categories, the number of which is determined by the user.

The end result?  Users would be able to organize jobs posts into categories that are important to them and **filter the Jobs list based on these sublists**.  For example, somebody may create the categories "Hell No!", "Maybe If Nothing Else Works Out", "Maybe", "Apply", "Applied".  Naturally they would be able to view the job posts in these sublists, but they should also be able to filter search results to exclude all job posts that appear in one (or all) of these categories.  This would make scanning through new job posts *so* much easier.

I also say the list of categories should be dynamic and based on the User because if we set a specific number of categories, naturally people will find more.  For example, I am currently looking into positions in several different states.  I may want to create a category for interesting jobs each state.

As it is now, Job posts never go away, even when you've already applied to them.  And scanning through the list of jobs can be daunting.

Perhaps SO could (eventually?) expand on these lists by adding support for default lists like "Viewed" (?), "Favorite" (✔), "Applied" (✔).

What say you?