# Jobs: How to block an employer (before any contact)?

Tags: support, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

There's a section [Blocked employers](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/blocked) on the `.../jobs/messages` page.

I couldn't find a way to add one there. The [Help Center section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/jobs) doesn't give a hint, either.

*[Edited after comments]*

I found [*Is there a way to block an employer request after the fact?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313018/1744774) but there's no

> big red button that says "Block Employer" near the top right

in my inbox or when displaying any of my messages. Steve says there in a comment

> That only applies if they message you

but not even that applies here. There are only green/red <kbd>I'm Interested</kbd>/<kbd>I'm Not Interested</kbd> buttons at the bottom of a message.

Comment: I've updated that answer to point to the current location, which is http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/inbox

Comment: @Stijn Thanks, but there's no "_big red button that says 'Block Employer' near the top right_" in my inbox or when displaying any of my messages. Steve says there "_That only applies if they message you_" but not even that applies here. There are only **I'm [Not] Interested** buttons at the bottom of a message.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to block the employer before they contact you? Seems like a strange request, I don't search Facebook for people to block before they try to friend me, I'm just not sure what the usefulness is in doing that?

Comment: @RonBeyer probably because there are [some known scams and predatory employers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332037/so-careers-should-stop-accepting-business-from-predatory-employers) on SO jobs and it would make the tool much nicer if we could hide/block those right from the get go.

Comment: @ssube Maybe there should be a flagging option or able to report them to site moderators? If they are predatory/scams then they need to be removed, not just blocked on a user-by-user basis... Blocking them for you doesn't help the next person they contact and drag in.

Comment: @RonBeyer another reason would be if you'd worked for a previous employer that you want to block and they are on SO jobs. Some people are less than professional when employees leave and those employees don't necessarily want to hear about it afterwards.

Comment: @RonBeyer It's what jammypeach mentions in his comment.

Comment: @RonBeyer Your solution doesn't work. As you can see in the linked question, sometimes SO Careers users and SO the company disagree on what is a predatory/scam company. A block button like Gerold suggested would allow each to maintain their own definitions.

Comment: Does this post need a `feature-request` tag?

Comment: I also think that blocking isn't the right way, specially since some people tend to have strong negative emotions about e previous employer, which may or may not be just personal issues. Therefore it wouldn't be good, if an employer gets blocked, just because one or two people had bad experiences. But instead of that, a rating and comment system might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the note! Re: blocking an employer **before any contact** - deferring that for now because it's not in our immediate plans. For the other portion ("blocking an employer after they message you"), if you don't mind opening as a separate issue, we should be able to treat that as a bug and take care of it.

Comment: @Davatar I think Gerold is proposing a personal block, not a block for all users.

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 Oh, in that case it would be a great idea and I support that.

Comment: It is also a waste of "ad space" if a person knows they do not want to work for them and their job ad/profile keeps appearing on posts on the right side.

Comment: @Donna I filed it as a bug: [Blocking an employer after they message you doesn't work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345571/1744774).

Comment: @epascarello And that fits right within SO's ad philosophy, which has been stated to be that showing you ads you don't want to see is a waste of time and money for them. Hopefully SO will reconsider their decision on no plans for personal blocks in the future.

Comment: Since the blocking required is personal, not a blocking for all users, I see no reason for not doing it. In fact, there are some companies I don't even want seeing my profile, since I know they are scams or predators or just completely disrespectful in their recruiting processes (like giving no feedback at all). I don't want to work for this kind of company and I don't even want them seeing my profile. I don't want ANY kind of contact with disrespectful people, whoever they are.