# Blocking an employer after they message you doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

According to a comment from [Donna](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4406529/donna) at [*Jobs: How to block an employer (before any contact)?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345399/1744774) I file this as a bug.

[Steve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148260/steve-trout) mentions in an answer to [*Is there a way to block an employer request after the fact?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313018/1744774) that

> there should be a big red button that says "Block Employer" near the top right

in the [inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/blocked) but there is none. Steve also mentions there in a comment

> That only applies if they message you

but that doesn't apply either. There are only green/red <kbd>I'm Interested</kbd>/<kbd>I'm Not Interested</kbd> buttons at the bottom of a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your bug report.

You should now be able to block an employer who has messaged you, even if you have not replied to the employer (or clicked Interested/Not Interested).  Please let us know if you continue to have problems with this feature.

Comment: The "Block Employer" button is there now. Thank you for the quick fix.